# How can I toggle stylesheet scripts and restore the original?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to implement a way to toggle between two `SASS` stylesheets in an `angular` project.   I create the stylesheets using the technique described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles). When i build using `ng build` it creates both `styles.js` and `contrast.js` in the output directory `dist/myProject`. All good so far.

In the project's root component, i have a function bound to a button's `(click)` event:

```
onThemeChange = () => {
  const script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  const defaultScript = document.querySelector('script[src="styles.js"]') as HTMLScriptElement;
  let source: string;
  if (null != defaultScript) {
    defaultScript.remove();
    source = 'dist/theme-test/contrast.js';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('script[src="dist/theme-test/contrast.js"]').remove();
    source = 'styles.js';
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  script.src = source;
}
```

Clicking the button produces the expected result - node

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
```

is replaced with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/theme-test/contrast.js"></script>
```

and the new stylesheet script is requested. When the request returns, the theme changes. The next click almost works as expected - the contrast script node is properly replaced in the `DOM` and the request is send, but the theme does not change when the request returns.

I have observed that the second request for `styles.js` always returns with status 304 but the request for `contrast.js` works as expected whether it returns with status 200 or 304, so it seems like that is not the issue but who knows...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
"extractCss": true,
```

in Angular.json file when you [ng build](https://angular.io/cli/build)

and use the css file instead of js file

Comment: I had to update the `start` script call in `package.json` to `ng serve --aot` in order to get this working in the development environment. After that, it was all good.